# Stable Diffusion use CPU instead of GPU

Tags: python, pytorch

Stable Diffusion give me a warning: "Warning: caught exception 'Found no NVIDIA driver on your system.", but I have AMD videocard. If I don't write "--skip-torch-cuda-test", console gives me exception: "Torch is not able to use GPU; add --skip-torch-cuda-test". When I start with this parametr, SD generate images with CPU when I change the settings on GPU. How to fix it? [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV5mE.png) [starting generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwvBk.png). I have Intel Core-i3 8100 CPU and AMD RX 580 8 Gb Videocard (if somebody interested) with driver AMD Software: Adrenaline Edition. Also in "set COMMANDLINE_ARGS=" I add "--precision full --no-half --skip-torch-cuda-test"

I reinstalled few times, tried to delete and paste "--skip-torch-cuda-test" (no results), generate with CPU and after with GPU (not worked, generate only with CPU anyway), changed resolution of picture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If I continue using my CPU instead of GPU for creating images, my PC will break soon. I want to fix this problem to make photos with my Videocard. How could I solve i?

Comment: If you're on Windows, you probably will need a Nvidia GPU. AMD only works under Linux, afaik. Your PC will not break, if it's cooling works.